# Problem uploading file in php

Tags: php

I have a simple but annoying problem and I don't understand the reason. I need to upload a simple csv file with php. Here's my code:

index.php:

```
<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

upload.php:

```
$upfile = "csv/".$_FILES["file"]["name"];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $upfile);
```

No errors whatsoever, but the file is still not uploaded on the server.

UPDATE: print_r($_FILES) output:

```
Array ( [fileUpload] => Array ( [name] => file1.csv [type] => text/comma-separated-values [tmp_name] => /var/tmp/php6YZ4Bt [error] => 0 [size] => 45 ) )
```

Comment: Update your post with `print_r($_FILES);`. But I'm going to take a shot in the dark to the most common cause - `csv/` isn't writable by PHP.

Comment: I think you should change the name "file" for like "fileUpload". And try with the full path in the $upfile var.

Comment: Does your server user have write permissions on csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to check

1) make sure your directory has permissions set to 755

2) check your path to see if it is correct.

3) make sure your post_max_size is the proper size.

4) make sure all your errors are turned on.
This can be done in the php script by using this code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); // or E_STRICT
ini_set("display_errors",1);
```

5) Increase your memory limit to see if the script is using more memory than previously allocated..

```
ini_set("memory_limit","1024M");
```